# QT Shell in Canopy

Tags: ipython, enthought, canopy

I've switched to Enthought's Canopy 1.0.0 but I miss the standalone QT shell and the QT notebook. I don't want to use the built-in shell which comes in the IDE. Where can I find the QT shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking about the IPython QtConsole? It and the Ipython notebook (NB this is not a QT notebook; it runs in a browser) are both accessible from the terminal / command prompt:

```
ipython qtconsole
ipython notebook
```

But you must have Canopy User Python on your PATH, as described [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-).

FWIW, the Python shell in Canopy *is* QtConsole, integrated with the editor and file browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the clarifications. And for creating Canopy of course, Enthought rocks!